# What is the best way to get a client ip in python?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am building an application that requires the client ip for geolocation purposes. I am using python, flask, and nginx to serve. From what I have read, common ip address capturing happens in the actual server. Any python script I use inevitably just returns my servers ip. What is the best way to get a client's ip address and pass it to the python scripts for further work to be done?

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-get-users-ip-address-using-flask/

Answer (score -1):

Although you're required to share part of your code to get help, I'm gonna answer your question: You can use Flask request.

```
from flask import request

...

client_ip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
client_port = request.environ['REMOTE_PORT']
```